# activeSelf not always recognised

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a strange problem that I can't fix. activeSelf is not always recognised as such when selected. Here's my code:

```
    public void OnMouseDown() 
    {
        // If tileback is showing, reveal the tile underneath.

        if (tileBack.activeSelf)
        {
            tileBack.SetActive(false);       // Reveal tile
            controller.TileRevealed(this);   // Let TileManager know
        }
        else
        {
            // This should only occur when a revealed tile is selected 
            // more than once:
            Debug.Log ("OnMouseDown - Not activeSelf"); 
            // However, occasionally it happens when a tile is selected
            // for the first time and so is active.
        }
    }
```

Under what circumstances could this happen?

**EDIT 1**

Prior to the above code being executed, the program first displays all the tiles face up (inactive), waits a few seconds, and displays the tiles face down (active).
For example:

```
    public IEnumerator Display(float waitTime)
    {
        DisplayTileFronts();
        
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

        DisplayTileBacks();
    }
```

If I don't display the tiles face up and just show the tiles face down, the problem goes away. However, the code to display tiles up and tiles down is identical apart from setting the tile's active state.
The length of the pause between the two doesn't have any effect.

What could be causing the problem?

**EDIT 2**
There seems to be no rational explanation for this error, so I must abandon the project as it's an integral part of the gameplay.

Comment: Please elaborate on the issue you are facing. What is the intent and what is happening? Might be [GameObject.activeInHierarchy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeInHierarchy.html) is what you need and not [GameObject.activeSelf](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeSelf.html). As __GameObject.activeSelf__ will return the local active state of the gameObject as per the documentation.

Comment: I have a set of tiles in a grid that can be selected individually. Once selected, they are turned over. The default state is face down (Active) and when selected they are turned over (Inactive).
The code shows that the selection usually works using activeSelf, but occasionally and randomly activeSelf is not recognised. I want to know how that could happen.

Comment: I should add that each tile front has an alphabetic letter (repeatable). The tile back is a child of the tile front. The same letter may be uncovered on separate clicks, as the letters are distributed randomly.

Comment: Use `Debug.Log ("OnMouseDown - Not activeSelf", tileBack);` and when the message is shown in the console window, you can click to see which tileBack is refered in the hierachy window.

Comment: That confirms it is not active when it should be, so I need to explore the grid setup logic, as that's the only place where it might not have been set properly. However, I'm puzzled as to why the tile back is showing when it's supposed to be inactive.

Comment: You abandoned the whole project just because of this issue? At that rate I don't know how you'd be able to finish any Unity project ever

Comment: It was an integral part of the plot and I couldn't figure out a workaround to what I regard as a bug, so  I deferred it while getting on with other projects.